# Terminal - ^[[H^[[2J - caret square bracket H caret square bracket 2 J

Tags: terminal, escape-characters

What does this command? I know that, the `CSI n ; m H` is for move the cursor to `n` row and `m` column, but what does command from title? `^[[H^[[2J` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a visual representation (where `^[` represents the ESC character) of the sequence to clear the screen and bring the cursor to the top in xterm-like terminals at least:

```
$ TERM=xterm tput clear | cat -v
^[[H^[[2J
```

To find out about those escape sequences, look at the [ctlseqs.txt](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) document shipped with `xterm`. There, you'll find:

> ESC [
>       Control Sequence Introducer (CSI  is 0x9b).

and:

> CSI Ps ; Ps H
>            Cursor Position [row;column] (default = [1,1]) (CUP).

and:

> CSI Ps J  Erase in Display (ED).
>              Ps = 0  -> Erase Below (default).
>              Ps = 1  -> Erase Above.
>              Ps = 2  -> Erase All.
>              Ps = 3  -> Erase Saved Lines (xterm).

(note that `^[[2J` doesn't clear the saved lines or alternate screen).

`tput clear` (or `clear`) on `xterm`-like terminals does the same as `printf '\e[H\e[2J'`. For that it queries the `terminfo` database to know what the sequence of character is for the `clear` capability for the terminal whose name is stored in the `$TERM` environment variable. If you dump the entry for the `xterm` terminal in the `terminfo` database with `infocmp xterm`, you'll see in  it:

```
$ infocmp -1 xterm | grep clear
        clear=\E[H\E[2J,
```

Which is another way to find out about a given escape sequence:

```
$ infocmp -L -1 | grep J
        clear_screen=\E[H\E[2J,
        clr_eos=\E[J,
```

(here using the `L`ong name for the capabilities). Then, you can do `man 5 terminfo` for a description of those capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The values `n` and `m` default to 1 in `CSIn;mH`, thus `^[[H` moves the cursor to the home position. `^[[2J` clears the screen, leaving the cursor where it is.

Comment: Not exactly; `^[[2J` clears the screen but does not move the cursor.

Comment: @egmont You are correct. I edited the answer.